# Add Maps to Fragment inside Fragment in Android

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, android-layout, android-fragments

I am making an Android App which basically has below structure.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.android.mortgagecalc.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now the `BottomNavigationView` switches between two fragments using below code.

```
if(fragment_id == FRAGMENT1) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.tab, new Fragment1(), "active");
    ft.commit();
} else if(fragment_id == FRAGMENT2) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.tab, new Fragment2(), "active");
    ft.commit();
} else {
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.tab, new Fragment1(), "active");
    ft.commit();
}
```

Now `Fragment2` has below layout's XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
        xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        sothree:umanoPanelHeight="68dp"
        sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp">

        <include

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/fragment2_map_layout"
            />

        <include
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/fragment2_list_layout"
            />

    </com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Fragment2 List"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, inside `fragment2_map_layout.xml` I want to add a Google Maps which will let me add custom markers. I have tried all the different ways that is available online. And have been getting exceptions and errors.

Can someone please suggest how to add Maps in such a project structure?

Can find whole code at https://github.com/keyurgolani/MortgageCalc for reference.

Comment: You added quite a few code, but missed the real ones. Provide map fragments class and layout codes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41195800/6648201 see if this helps

Comment: You can check the project at https://github.com/keyurgolani/MortgageCalc for full code reference